# Export values from JSP page to a csv file using web application

Tags: java, file, jsp, servlets, csv

Below is the code of my JSP page from which I need to call one of the method in my Class.

```
<p class='pos1'>&nbsp;<a href="" target="_blank">
<img class="csvFile"    src="/images/logo.gif"/>&nbsp;Export</a></p>
```

As soon as I click on Export link, I want to call a method in my class which is exportToCSVFiles() by passing an object called data. Here data contains some value -

```
public class TestExport {

    public static void exportToCSVFiles(final Object object) {
        System.out.println("hello world");
    }
}
```

Is it possible to do that?or any help would be really appreciated

Comment: What is mean by `href="#headerDiv"`? If you want to pass your data to servlet you need to add your servlet name in href property.

Comment: that was just by mistake.. Can you tell me if I am passing the name of my servlet only, then how can I identify that this call is coming from an hyperlink call bcoz then basis on that, I will have my if else bock to do what's needed?

Comment: You can pass some parameter `(servletName?action=export)` with your servlet name, so you can identify based on parameter presence. But i don't understand what is the object you are going to pass from jsp and you are not providing any information about that.